# jquery mobile dynamically create a radio button and listen to click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am surprisingly stuck at a very unusual place trying to create a radio button and listening to click events on it.

The HTML page is as follows:

```
<h4><b>Header</b><span class="pull-right app-selected-title"></span></h4>
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" class="app-ct-child-holder"></fieldset>
```

And the javascript is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("pagecreate","#pageOne",function(){
        $(".app-ct-child-holder").append('<label class="app-radio"><input type="radio" class="app-radio-chk" name="t" data-nm="test_name" id="1" data-tl="Title">Click me</label>');
        $(".app-ct-child-holder").controlgroup("refresh");
        $(".app-ct-child-holder").trigger("create");
        $(document).on('click', '.app-radio-chk', function() {
            alert('hi');
        });
    });
</script>
```

In my HEAD, I have the following included

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

I cannot understand what am I missing. But the alert just doesn't come. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Is your problem that your radiogroup actually renders well, but click event does not work ? And why not trying `$(".app-radio-chk").click(function(){alert('hi)})`

Comment: this  is whats causing the problem -- ($(".app-ct-child-holder").controlgroup("refresh");
        $(".app-ct-child-holder").trigger("create");) -- https://jsfiddle.net/2rh5947r/  -- what are you trying to achieve by adding those. maybe you should use https://api.jquerymobile.com/enhancewithin/

Comment: @ardabeyazoglu that did not work since it is a dynamically added component. Hence .live(), .on() or .bind() might be required.

Comment: @Tasos Thanks for the jsfiddle. I apologize for not having mentioned that I had tried not doing `controlgroup("refresh")` or `trigger("create")`. This doesnt render the radio button, the jQuery way. I can see in your example that you have avoided these statements and the event gets captured. Anyway I can get both? For the `enhanceWithin()`, [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frfwdqoa/) will show what I tried with `enhanceWithin()`.

Comment: This is actually working as i tried in your fiddle: 
`$(contents).appendTo( ".app-ct-child-holder" ).trigger('create');`
`$(document).on('click', '.app-radio-chk', function() {alert('hi');});`

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is not the dynamically added radio button. The problem is that you can't access the input field. Thats because of the way, jqm styles the elements.

The `<input>` element has a css style `z-index: 1` and the `<label>` has the css style `z-index: 2` 
Because of that you don't see the the input field on the screen. If you don't see a element, you can't click it. Change your click-listener to the label and everything should work fine.